# identical rows into columns csv python

Tags: python, csv

i have the following csv file which i want to convert into the output, basically it reads the the first column value as key and then append the next value into column

**input.csv**

```
a.jpg,a,b
a.jpg,c,d
b.jpg,e,f
b.jpg,g,h
c.jpg,i,j
c.jpg,k,l
c.jpg,m,n
c.jpg,o,p
c.jpg,q,r
d.jpg,s,t
d.jpg,u,v
e.jpg,w,x
e.jpg,y,z
```

**output.csv**

```
a.jpg a,b c,d
b.jpg e,f g,h
c.jpg i,j k,l m,n o,p q,r
d.jpg s,t u,v
e.jpg w,x y,z
```

i tried the following, but still can't figure out how to unpack the value to output csv based on desired format above

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as input_csv, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_csv:

filename = {}

for row in csv.reader(input_csv):
    if row[0] not in filename:
        filename[row[0]]=[[row[1],row[2]]]
    else:
        filename[row[0]].append([row[1],row[2]])

for item in filename.items():
    print(item)
```

**the output**

```
('a.jpg', [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']])
('b.jpg', [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']])
('c.jpg', [['i', 'j'], ['k', 'l'], ['m', 'n'], ['o', 'p'], ['q', 'r']])
('d.jpg', [['s', 't'], ['u', 'v']])
('e.jpg', [['w', 'x'], ['y', 'z']])
```

Comment: are you opposed to using pandas to alter the .csv files ?

Comment: @KaranShishoo not really though, i'm still experimenting using python dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this

```py
import pandas as pd
```

Read input CSV file as:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',header=None)
```

Group the data by first column:

```py
dff =df.groupby(0).apply(lambda x: list(x[1])+list(x[2]))
```

Write each group values to an output CSV file

```py
for i in dff.iteritems():
    with open('output.csv','a') as out:
        out.write(','.join([i[0]]+i[1])+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code without `pandas`:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as input_csv, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_csv:

    filename = {}

    for row in csv.reader(input_csv):
        if row[0] in filename:
            my_list = [row[1],row[2]]
            filename[row[0]].append(my_list)
        elif row[0] not in filename:
            filename[row[0]]=[[row[1],row[2]]]

    for item in filename:
        output_csv.write('{} {}\n'.format(item,
            ' '.join([','.join(l) for l in filename[item]])))
```

Basically I've changed only last two lines.

Firstly we need to iterate through the dictionary and then write lines for each entry. The last line concatenates the key with the value. The value itself is a joined list items, made in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this will work for you.

```
dic = {}

for row in csv.reader(input_csv):
    key, *values = row.split(",")
    if key not in dic:
        dic[key] = []
    for value in values:
        dic[key].append(value)

for key, value in dic.items():
    value = ", ".join(value)
    print(f"{key} {value}")
```

output:

```
a.jpg a, b, c, d
b.jpg e, f, g, h
c.jpg i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r
d.jpg s, t, u, v
e.jpg w, x, y, z
```